# Syntax for mod_rewrite to exempt urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What is the best way to tell mod_rewrite to stop processing rules on a list of urls?

Normally you would do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^/foo
RewriteRule a b [L]
```

Only if there are more rules, you need to make sure they don't apply to ^/foo again!

What's a good way to say:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} ^/foo
#no rewrite rules apply ever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `RewriteRule` itself can match the URI, you don't need to use a `RewriteCond`. One `RewriteRule` for which the rewritten action is just a `-` hyphen with the `[L]` flag should prevent the matching path from ever being rewritten.

```
# First prevent /foo from rewriting later
# This rule matches /foo and takes *no action* 
RewriteRule ^foo - [L]

# Other rules may follow...
# For example a generic rewrite in common use
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
RewriteCond (.*) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Note: I used `^foo` assuming this would be used in context of .htaccess. If you were using it at the server level, you would need to include the leading `/` as in `^/foo`.